# C# Creating a DataTable from not fully-known JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, parsing, azure-functions

I have an Azure function written in C# which receives JSON by HTTP POST request, in which I am sure about nodes: ssid, dim, type, list_of_business_keys. Each item in the list, has one or more columns, which name and type I do not know, before I receive the JSON. Let's say that for the first example they are column_1 and column_2, both of Int64 type:

```
{ "ssid" : 1, 
  "dim" : 2,
  "type" : 3,
  "list_of_business_keys":
  [
      {"business_key" : {"column_1" : 100, "column_2" : 1000}},
      {"business_key" : {"column_1" : 200, "column_2" : 1000}},
      {"business_key" : {"column_1" : 300, "column_2" : 1000}},
      {"business_key" : {"column_1" : 400, "column_2" : 1000}},
      {"business_key" : {"column_1" : 500, "column_2" : 1000}}
  ]
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to convert this JSON to a DataTable, that I would later use as a table type parameter to invoke a Stored Procedure from Azure SQL Database. So I would like this DataTable to look like this:

[image]

I have written following code to achieve that:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Net"
#r "System.Data"

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string resultAsString = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    KeyList keyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyList>(resultAsString);

    List<ListOfBusinessKey> list = keyList.list_of_business_keys;

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ssid", typeof(Int64)));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dim", typeof(Int64)));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("type", typeof(Int64)));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("column_1", typeof(Int64)));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("column_2", typeof(Int64)));



    foreach (var key in list) {
        tbl.Rows.Add(keyList.ssid, keyList.dim, keyList.type, key.business_key.column_1, key.business_key.column_2);  
    }

    foreach (var row in tbl.Rows){
        log.Info(row.ToString());
    }

    foreach (DataRow dataRow in tbl.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
        {
            log.Info(item.ToString());
        }
    }

    return req.CreateResponse(keyList);

}

public class BusinessKey
{
    public int column_1 { get; set; }
    public int column_2 { get; set; }
}

public class ListOfBusinessKey
{
    public BusinessKey business_key { get; set; }
}

public class KeyList
{
    public int ssid { get; set; }
    public int dim { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public List<ListOfBusinessKey> list_of_business_keys { get; set; }
}
```

And this seems to work.

My problem is that to deserialize received JSON I have to create classes based on JSON's structure. The same is with creating the data table. I know the col names and their types so I create the DataTable implicitly. But what happens when I do not know the structure before?

So let's now I assume that I receive following JSON:

```
{ "ssid" : 1, 
  "dim" : 2,
  "type" : 3,
  "list_of_business_keys":
  [
      {"business_key" : {"xxx" : "abc", "yyy" : 1000, "zzz" : 123}},
      {"business_key" : {"xxx" : "cde", "yyy" : 1000, "zzz" : 456}},
      {"business_key" : {"xxx" : "efg", "yyy" : 1000, "zzz" : 789}},
      {"business_key" : {"xxx" : "hij", "yyy" : 1000, "zzz" : 12 }},
      {"business_key" : {"xxx" : "klm", "yyy" : 1000, "zzz" : 345}}
  ]
}
```

and I would like to receive following DT:

[image]

Is this possible to change the code, to "dynamically" convert JSON to desired format of DataTable? If yes, what should I do to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much of the JSON schema is fixed vs variable?  Are the properties `"ssid"`, `"dim"` and `"type"` fixed?  Are the properties `"list_of_business_keys"` and `"business_key"` fixed?

Comment: `"ssid", "dim", "type", "list_of_business_keys"` and `"business_key"` are fixed. Changeable are only nodes inside `business key` (`"xxx", "yyy", "zzz"` in this example). Of course inside one JSON all of these business key columns will have the same name (no situation, that we have `xxx` in one row and `aaa` instead in second row)

Comment: I'm also wondering, if using JSONs like: `{"ssid" : 1, "dim" : 2, "type" : 3, {"business_key" : {"xxx" : "abc", "yyy" : 1000, "zzz" : 123}}},{"ssid" : 1, "dim" : 2, "type" : 3, {"business_key" : {"xxx" : "abc", "yyy" : 1000, "zzz" : 123}}}` would make it simplier to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `business_key` as a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then dynamically populate the `DataTable` based on the property names and data types actually encountered in the JSON file.

Define the following types and extension methods:

```
public class ListOfBusinessKey
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> business_key { get; set; }
}

public class KeyList
{
    public int ssid { get; set; }
    public int dim { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public List<ListOfBusinessKey> list_of_business_keys { get; set; }

    public DataTable ToDataTable()
    {
        var tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ssid", typeof(Int64)));
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dim", typeof(Int64)));
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("type", typeof(Int64)));

        var columnQuery = EnumerableExtensions.Merge(
            list_of_business_keys
            .SelectMany(k => k.business_key)
            .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, Type>(p.Key, p.Value == null ? typeof(object) : p.Value.GetType())),
            p => p.Key, (p1, p2) => new KeyValuePair<string, Type>(p1.Key, MergeTypes(p1.Value, p2.Value)));
        foreach (var c in columnQuery)
            tbl.Columns.Add(c.Key, c.Value);

        foreach (var d in list_of_business_keys.Select(k => k.business_key))
        {
            var row = tbl.NewRow();
            row["ssid"] = ssid;
            row["dim"] = dim;
            row["type"] = type;
            foreach (var p in d.Where(p => p.Value != null))
            {
                row[p.Key] = Convert.ChangeType(p.Value, tbl.Columns[p.Key].DataType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            tbl.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return tbl;
    }

    static Type MergeTypes(Type type1, Type type2)
    {
        // Enhance as needed
        if (type1 == type2)
            return type1;
        if (type2 == typeof(object))
            return type1;
        if (type1 == typeof(object))
            return type2;
        if (type1.IsAssignableFrom(type2))
            return type1;
        if (type2.IsAssignableFrom(type1))
            return type2;
        if (typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(type1) && typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(type2))
        {
            if (type1 == typeof(string))
                return type1;
            if (type2 == typeof(string))
                return type2;
            if ((type1 == typeof(long) || type1 == typeof(int)) && (type2 == typeof(decimal) || type2 == typeof(double)))
                return type2;
            if ((type2 == typeof(long) || type2 == typeof(int)) && (type1 == typeof(decimal) || type1 == typeof(double)))
                return type1;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Cannot merge types {0} and {1}", type1, type2));
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Merge<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> mergeSelector)
    {
        if (source == null || keySelector == null || mergeSelector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return MergeIterator(source, keySelector, mergeSelector);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> MergeIterator<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TSource, TSource> mergeSelector)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TSource>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            var key = keySelector(element);
            TSource oldElement;
            if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out oldElement))
            {
                dictionary[key] = element;
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary[key] = mergeSelector(element, oldElement);
            }
        }
        return dictionary.Values;
    }
}
```

Then deserialize and convert to a `DataTable` as follows:

```
var keyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyList>(json);
var tbl = keyList.ToDataTable();
```

Note there is some awkwardness required to deal with situations where one of the `"business_key"` properties is first encountered with a null value and later encountered with a non-null value, or first encountered with an integral value and later encountered with a decimal or double value.  In such cases the more general type needs to be preferred over the initially encountered type.

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jd9biI).

**Update**

The purpose of `EnumerableExtensions.Merge()` and `MergeTypes()` is to infer a correct `Type` to use for for `DataColumn.DataType` by looking through all the cells that will get added to the column and choosing a "most appropriate" type by merging the observed types of each cell.  Compared to simply looking at the cells in the first row, this handles situations like:

1. The first row contains a `null` cell.  In such cases subsequent rows mush be checked.
2. The first row contains a cell with an integer value like `123` but a subsequent row has a cell with a floating-point value like `12.123`.  In this case the type inferred needs to switch from `long` to `double` or `decimal`.
3. The first row contains a cell with a numeric value like `1000` but a subsequent row has a cell with a string value like `"Unknown"` or `"$122.22"` (or whatever).  In this case the type inferred needs to switch to `string`.
4. Two cells that will be added to the same column have completely incompatible types such as `long` and `DateTime`.  In this case an exception is thrown.

Newtonsoft's own [`DataTableConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs) infers `DataColumn.DataType` only from the first row, which periodically causes problems like the ones from *[DateTime column type becomes String type after deserializing DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37109154/3744182)* and *[deserialize a datatable with a missing first column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32726718/3744182)*.  The code in this answer takes advantage of the fact that the entire JSON was pre-loaded into a `JToken` hierarchy to avoid those problems.

The third sample JSON string in the [example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jd9biI) includes samples of cases #1-#3.

If you are sure none of the above can happen you could simplify `MergeTypes()` to simply throw an exception when the types are not identical.

Comment: Hi @dbc, that's a perfect piece of code that really does, what I tried to achieve. It works very well in VS, but there is a problem when I try to use the code inside `.csx` script (and this is what I use when writing Azure Function in C#). For every Extended function I get a similar error message: `[Error] run.csx(71,33): error CS1109: Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class; KeyListExtensions is a nested class`. Is there a way to somehow work it out? Of course all of these classes are not nested.

Comment: `Environment version: 4.0.30319.42000`
`Json.NET version: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed` If it's needed

Comment: @Jangcy - seems like this is a limitation of csx scripts, see [How to define an extension method in a scriptcs csx script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16948562).  Solution is to make the extension methods into object methods or plain old static methods.  Answer updated.

Comment: I've managed to deal with that limitation by adding the extension methods in another .csx file and loading it into the main one. After some modifications your method works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @dbc. I know that it has been a while now, but could you please explain what do your methods: merge, mergeIterator, mergeSelector, mergeTypes do? I just want to be sure that I completely understand what happens in this piece of code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It smells like a solution for NoSql database. e.g. Azure Table Storage
You can have different column names for different object types.

[Azure table storage store multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450819/azure-table-storage-store-multiple-types)

Answer (score 0):

First create function to convert jsonstring to datatable:

```
   public DataTable JsonStringToDataTable(string jsonString)
   {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      string[] jsonStringArray = Regex.Split(jsonString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), "},{");
      List<string> ColumnsName = new List<string>();
      foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
      {
         string[] jsonStringData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
         foreach (string ColumnsNameData in jsonStringData)
         {
            try
            {
               int idx = ColumnsNameData.IndexOf(":");
               string ColumnsNameString = ColumnsNameData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
               if (!ColumnsName.Contains(ColumnsNameString))
               {
                  ColumnsName.Add(ColumnsNameString);
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Error Parsing Column Name : {0}", ColumnsNameData));
            }
         }
         break;
      }
      foreach (string AddColumnName in ColumnsName)
      {
         dt.Columns.Add(AddColumnName);
      }
      foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
      {
         string[] RowData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
         DataRow nr = dt.NewRow();
         foreach (string rowData in RowData)
         {
            try
            {
               int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
               string RowColumns = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
               string RowDataString = rowData.Substring(idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
               nr[RowColumns] = RowDataString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               continue;
            }
         }
         dt.Rows.Add(nr);
      }
      return dt;
   }
```

Then call this function :

```
 string FileName = "JSONString.txt";
 var stream = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath(FileName));
 string JsonString = stream.ReadToEnd();
 DataTable dt = JsonStringToDataTable(JsonString);
```