# How to handle entity casting errors with Azure Storage Table Service

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I fear this might be quite the simple question, but honestly I've read the documentation and I don't understand.

When using an Azure Storage Table, I understand that I set a Partition and Row Key then pass in the object I want to have saved in the entity.

Now, these are my questions?
Once the first object is set, can subsquent objects have different structure?

What if I don't know the structure of an entity. Can I use a URL to discover it?

Without using Azure Storage explorer, is there any way to retrieve the structure of objects on a list of entities?

Comment: This question will guide you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450819/azure-table-storage-store-multiple-types

Comment: But I don't understand, is this saying that the SDK will do it's best to fill in public properties that match in name and type and not throw errors on the rest? Is that the nature of the no-sql part?

Answer (score 0):

Every row in an azure table can have a completely different type of object, so the answer to your 1st question is yes.

If you do not know the structure of the entity stored, then you can retrieve the entity as `DynamicTableEntity`. `DynamicTableEntity` comes with an `EntityProperty` dictionary. The key in the dictionary is the name of the property and the value is the `EntityProperty`. The `EntityProperty` contains both a `PropertyType` property and the actual value of the property from the original object. This should give you a good idea of the shape of the object that is written to table storage. There is no URL functionality to get the type.

Comment: That's a really good answer! One question though, how do most designers deal with the fact that the object graph could be different each time?

Comment: In most cases in my experience, people working with a schema less db either own the db personally or within the team, or collaborate with the team that owns the table so they have some if not full knowledge of what is in the db. Data model changes are communicated through before hand etc. If there are different types of objects are written to the same table (does not have to be that way) one method I use is to  prefix row keys or partition keys with a certain string to differentiate the object type written to that row in other words use a unique partition/row key patterns for different types.